# Check existence of certain row in Cell-Array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, exists

Assuming I've got a cell Array like this:

```
1x25 double   1x25 double   1x25 double   1x11 double   'Mean'
1000          0             0             5                0
1000          10            5             100              0    
1000          20            5             200              0    
1000          30            5             100              0
```

And now I'd like to check if there is ANY row in this cell array where the first column is `1000`, the second column is `30` and the third column is `5` and the fourth column is `100` - how to do that? The first row should be neglected as there are only column headers in it.

I came up with quite a strange approach:

```
sum(sum([[data{2:end, 1}]'==1000  [data{2:end, 2}]'==30 [data{2:end, 3}]'==5 [data{2:end, 4}]'==100], 2)==4)
```

Whereas the result has to be `> 0` so that there is at least one occurrence of data-tupel...
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: I came up with:

```
found = ismember([1000 30 5 100], cell2mat(data(2:end, 1:4)), 'rows')
```

I think this solution is quite good - but if you've got an even better approach, just post it. It doesn't need to be fast, just has to be readable and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps simpler:

```
all(bsxfun(@eq, cell2mat(data(2:end,1:4)), [1000 30 5 100]),2)
```

Another possibility (probably slower):

```
arrayfun(@(n) all([data{n,1:4}]==[1000 30 5 100]),(2:size(data,1)).')
```

Comment: It's also good, but I like the "ismember" better because it's more intuitive as the function-name yields what the function might be doing :)

Comment: @bjoern Well, to me, the name `@eq` is just as intuitive :-)

Comment: Yeah, why not ;-) Wether I accept or not, makes no diff, thus accepting it now ;-)